# MVC DropDownList causing exception on form submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add a **DropDownList** to an MVC **View** and keep getting the below error. This occures after clicking form submit. Can anyone help shed some light on what this means and how I can resolve it?

**The error message**

```
The ViewData item that has the key 'Amount' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.
```

For context, here is how I've setup the **Model** and **View** that led to the aforementioned error

**For the model...**

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), Name = "ApplicationAmountLabel")]
public string Amount { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Amounts { get; set; }
```

When the model is setup, here is how the value is set...

```
model.Amounts = GetAmounts();

...

private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetAmounts(List<int> amounts)
{
    var list = new List<SelectListItem>();

    list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = string.Empty, Value = "0" });

    foreach (var amount in amounts)
    {
        list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = amount.ToString("C"), Value = amount.ToString() });
    }

    return list;
}
```

**Finally, here is how this is used in the View...**

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Amount)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Amount, Model.Amounts, "-- Select One --")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Amount)
```

Comment: Excellent error message says it all.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible cause of this error message is the `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Amounts { get; set; }` property of you model is null, after submitting the form. Before sending the POSTED model to the view, set the value of the `Amounts` property:

```
 model.Amounts = GetAmounts();
```

This exception is thrown by the `Html.DropDownListFor()` 
helper method while the `selectList` argument is null. If the `selectList` argument is null, the helper method tries to get the items for the `selectList` parameter from the ViewData by the name of the property expression (`m => m.Amount`), which is `Amount` here. It will get the value by the name `Amount` from ViewData, and it is of type `String`, but it expects of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like the signature of the controller action to which the form is submitted has the wrong type for Amount (it its occurring as you click submit)